# Why in ElCapitan GM and Xcode 7 GM the popover appears outside of the view?

Tags: swift2, xcode7

Does someone knows why in ElCapitan GM and Xcode 7 GM the popover appears outside of the view?

The popover is triggered by the "Button".

The picture below is a new project with no code written by me, jut a button.

Is it a bug or a new "feature"?

[image: Print screen]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just tried it, and it seems that you can't set the popover anchor in the Storyboard. Perhaps this is indeed a bug in the new release.

To display the popover programmatically, set the StoryboardID of your popover view controller, for example: "PopoverViewController". Below, it's implemented in the main view controller as a lazy var, so it's instantiated just once, the first time it's referenced.

Connect an IBAction from your button to the main view controller — here, a function called "displayPopover". The "guard let" statement makes sure the sender can be cast as an NSButton.

Then, just call:
 `presentViewController:asPopover...`

```
lazy var popoverViewController: NSViewController = {
    return self.storyboard!.instantiateControllerWithIdentifier("PopoverViewController")
        as! NSViewController
    }()

@IBAction func displayPopover(sender: AnyObject) {

    guard let button = sender as? NSButton else {return}

    self.presentViewController(popoverViewController, asPopoverRelativeToRect: button.frame, ofView: button, preferredEdge: NSRectEdge.MaxY, behavior: NSPopoverBehavior.Transient)

}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. This is my best option.